# Crash on UIImagePickerController AVErrorUnknown=-11800

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Reproducing on iPhone 5S with iOS 8.3.
It fails with code -11800 which is `AVErrorUnknown`

> Camera: Error capturing still image (Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be
>   completed" UserInfo=0x175672140 {NSUnderlyingError=0x176655c00 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -16800.)",
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16800),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed})

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue,
and the problem was the *forced autofocus* of camera that i've used.

I've the same phone and the same iOS.

In particular,

```
device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus
```

used in this snippet:

```
- (void) forceFocus {
    NSArray * devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
    NSError * error;
    for ( AVCaptureDevice * device in devices ) {
        if ( [device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack ) {
            [device lockForConfiguration:&error];
            if ( [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus] ) {
                device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus;
            }
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

If you use something like that, try to remove the autofocus.
Should solve the issue.